# docker-compose project root reference

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file at the root of my project, and within that project there are several modules in sub-directories.

I find that I can issue docker-compose commands from anywhere within the project root and these work, compose seems to search backwards until it finds the docker-compose file. This is useful.

However, it does not locate the .env file in the project root, it seems to want to find the file in the current folder so `docker-compose up` commands don't work and I imagine volume mounts that reference folders relative to the docker-compose file may not work either.

How can I change my docker-compose file to such that these references refer to the a location relative to the docker-compose.yml file itself?